# "Saving wrappers to '/Users/USER/.rvm/bin'........" every time terminal opens

Tags: macos, terminal, rvm, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Every time I open a terminal, this message appears before login:

```
Saving wrappers to '/Users/USER/.rvm/bin'........
```

This just recently started, and may be related to me changing permissions on .rvm or its subdirectories. I use zsh and oh-my-zsh and am on OSX 10.8.3

Anybody know what causes this and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have activated the `after_use_textmate` hook, you can disable it with:

```
chmod -x $rvm_path/hooks/after_use_textmate
```

or disable all hooks with:

```
chmod -x $rvm_path/hooks/*
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Look like I enabled all the hooks when I changed some perms inside of ~/.rvm

Answer (score 0):

The "RVM" in question is Ruby.

Q: Have you done some kind of Ruby-related update recently?

SUGGESTION: `rvm get stable`, then `rvm use ruby`